# What are the alternative to PHP session variables?

Tags: php, session-variables

I am writing a brand new website and I'd like to make sure that it scales out easily if I ever get to the point where I must host the site on multiple machines with a load balancer.

The user of the website can be authenticated. In other words, I need to maintain some state information. My first reflex was to use Session variables but then I am going to be limited to a single machine. I know that there are ways to store the session variables outside (in a DB, redis, memcached) but is that the only options?

What are the alternative to session variable? How Facebook and other big web sites are doing this?

P.S. I am not looking for another session handler (DB, redis, etc.). I'd like to know if there a way to completely get rid of session variables.

Comment: It's a good question, but if I may offer a piece of unsolicited advice: in many cases it really is better to just not worry about scaling at all in the early stages of a project. Unless you're doing something real unusual, I think it's unlikely that session storage will be a bottleneck.

Comment: I see your point Eli. But I am not worrying about session variable being a bottleneck... I just want to make sure that the service scales out without too much work. It looks like session variable is the way to go. I was hopping there would be a better way to do this in 2012... I would be interested to know how StackOverflow does it...

Answer (score 8):

Ever heard of [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)? It allows you to use mechanisms other than the default PHP session handler (the one that writes sess_xxxxxxxxxxxx files in tmp directory).

You can write your own session handler that uses a database. This could be a time consuming task; so you can stick with the default PHP session handlers for the time being and transparently switch to database when you are ready. You probably won't have to rewrite any code except implementing and plugging in your version of the six session handling functions.

Comment: Bingo. To further answer the question, this is the sort of thing Facebook does (via memcached, IIRC).

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz! Is there an article somewhere which documents that? I am surprised to know that Facebook uses session variables...

Comment: Why would you be surprised to know that? They're necessary for pretty much anything a social network would do - login status, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into caching, i.e using [Zend cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) or [APC cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), for example.

Comment: It would be useful if you could, at least, link to documentation that describes how these could be used to share state information on a per-user basis.